Hub parameters are not arriving to my callback URL in WhatsApp Business API
I'm implementing the WhatsApp Cloud API, one of the steps to do it it's subscribe to webhooks and verify them using three parameters: hub.mode, hub.challenge and hub.verify_token.
We have tried sending webhook tests from several sources and tools to send petitions to the API and we have also sent messages to the WhatsApp account that is being handled by the API, and in none of these tests the Hub parameters are appearing. As it's shown in the image, we are expecting the parameters are shown in a Get array.
This is how the log is looking in my Callback URL
array (
)POST


GETarray (

This is how the log should look
array (
)POST



GETarray (
  'hub_mode' => 'subscribe',
  'hub_challenge' => '<challenge number>',
  'hub_verify_token' => '<token>',
)


The query string and the request URI should show the hub parameters too, but it doesn't.
What are we missing?

"We have tried sending webhook tests from several sources and tools to send petitions to the API and we have also sent messages to the WhatsApp account" - that is of course pointless; you can not expect to receive webhook notifications, before you have not even set up your webhook properly yet.

You should get those parameters in the verification stage of registering your webhook URL, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/getting-started#verification-requests

Very hard to tell what's going on as we there doesn't seem to be much info to work with...
Please provide some more context so we can try help...

What framework are you using - Nodejs/Typescript/Python?
Have you verified your webhook with the initial get request?
How are you testing - with Graph Explorer or Postman?
How are you parsing the Meta Webhook?
In the Meta Developer Console you can see the expected payload and test the webhook for a specific permission
Are you WABA numbers verified and ready to send?

It's always good to read over the docs and hopefully find it's a small & easy fix
